# How to solve the word problem below?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, circles, plane-geometry, word-problem

[image]

Can anyone guide me through this problem? I know how to solve the equation of the circle (the Earth) below but I don't know how to solve the equation of the orbit.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Since you are new here I wanted to let you know/tell you a few things. Please do not use pictures for critical parts of your post. Pictures are inaccesable to screen-readers and cannot be searched. Also, try to make your title more informative. In general, [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/145141) can be quite useful to newcommers.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the formula for the circumference of the Earth as
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2,$$
which is the formula for the circle of radius $r$ centered at the point $(a,b)$. Assuming that the orbit of the satellite is not at an angle with respect to the map, all you need to do is increase the radius.

Answer (score 0):

The radius of orbit is 0.6 units more than radius of earth and centre is same as that of earth

Answer (score 0):

The radius of the circle is $64$. We may as well move its center to $(0,0)$. The orbit of the satellite then appears as an ellipse with mayor semiaxis $a:=64.6$ and minor semiaxis $b\leq a$. We are not told the direction of these axes. Therefore we shall assume the major axis in direction ${\bf u}:=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ and the minor axis in direction ${\bf v}:=(-\sin\alpha,\cos\alpha)$. A parametric representation of the elllipse is then given by
$${\bf z}(t):=a \cos t\>{\bf u}+ b\sin t\>{\bf v}\qquad(0\leq t\leq2\pi)\ ,$$
or in coordinates:
$$x(t)=a\cos\alpha\cos t-b\sin\alpha\sin t,\quad y(t)=a\sin\alpha\cos t +b\cos\alpha\sin t\ .$$